# Is it possible to pass an API Gateway variable into a Lambda Context?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'd quite like to be able to use context.stage in a Lambda call, passed in from the API gateway context - but I can only see how to put it into the message body (event object).
Is there any way to add arbitrary information to the Lambda Context?

Comment: Modifying the context is not supported through the Lambda integration. Is there a reason including this information in the payload is insufficient?

Answer (score 4):

I believe your only option is to add it to the event. You can always extract the value at the start of your Lambda function and then delete the property.

The Rest API example from AWS does something similar:

```
var operation = event.operation;
delete event.operation;
```